# Round double value to 2 decimal digits

Tags: java, android, scientific-notation

I have been working with big numbers (with more that 20 digits) and for that reason I use `Double` . The form I get the numbers is like this **8.653762536765E28**.
What I want to do is just display the first 2 decimal digits. I want it like **8.65E28**.

I tried to find about formatting double values but I wan't able to do it. The result I was getting was 86537...12312.00 .

What do you thing is a good approach for this case? How can I manage only the digits in front of the E (the base) and not the whole number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you want to achieve:

```
 double d = 8.653762536765E28;
 DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("0.00E0");
 System.out.print(df.format(d));
```

Comment: Yes I didn't know I could use the E like a value! thank you!